# Checking if the Hessian is the derivative of the gradient

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, finite-differences, floating-point

Suppose $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$. I have a code that computes the gradient of $f$. I have another code that computes the Hessian of $f$ times a vector. Now I want to check if they are correct. Specifically, I am checking of the Hessian times vector is the directional derivative of the gradient.

I have

> Hessian(x).v \approx (1/h) * (grad(x+h.v) - grad(x)) where h is a scalar.

Define:

> fderror:= (Hessian.v - (1/h) * ( grad(x+h.v) - grad(x))))^T (Hessian.v - (1/h) * ( grad(x+h.v) - grad(x)))).

For some reasons, as $h$ decreases, my $\text{fderror}$ increases and vice versa. And when $h$ is around `1e-10`, my $\text{fderror}$ is around `1e+00`.

Is it due to floating point
or my Hessian-times-vector is not correct?

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: If you are still interested in an answer please translate what your code (underlined in grey) is doing, using mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Well $1e-10$ is both small enough and large enough that it could either be rounding error, or a problem with your code. It's hard to say without further information.

1. A good rule of thumb is to check to somewhere a bit less than the square root of machine epsilon. I like to go with $1e-6$ or $1e-7$.
2. Run your code with a sequence of progressively smaller finite difference sizes $h$ and make a plot of error vs. $h$ on a logarithmic scale. If everything is correct you should see a straight line going down until machine precision where it starts to get a little weird. Here is a plot of what it should look like if your code is correct:
   [image: finite difference error plot]
3. It's very common to use approximations to the Hessian (eg., Gauss-Newton approximation), in which case one would expect to have error that does not go away as you make $h$ smaller.

For reference, the Matlab code to generate the above plot is,

> ```
> x0 = randn;
> dx = randn;
> hh = 10.^(-(1:0.5:15)); 
> diff = (cos(x0 + hh*dx)-cos(x0))./hh; 
> true = -sin(x0)*dx; 
> err = abs(true - diff); 
> plot(-log(hh),log(err))
> ```